# Mocking framework from Microsoft?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I want to start using mock objects on my c# project.

After a quick google I've found that most folks use one of the below:

- NMock
- EasyMock.Net
- TypeMock Isolator
- Rhino Mocks
- Moq

Does Microsoft provide a similar framework for mocking? I'm using Visual Studio tests for my unit test now.

Comment: you may also want to look at xUnit.net which is the testing frame used by kzu, author of moq. xUnit.net is from Jim Newkirk (a developer of NUnit 2.0) and Brad Wilson, both Microsoft employees. Jim Newkirk manages codeplex where you can find http://xunit.codeplex.com and follow #xunit at @xunit http://twitter.com/xunit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microsoft does not have any official public mock object frameworks. We do have some internal ones that we've used before (I work at Microsoft). In recent times we have prefered to use publicly available libraries because we give out the source code to both the projects and unit tests of many of our projects and we'd like the public (that's you!) to be able to compile and run these projects.

On my team (ASP.NET) we now most often use [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). The author (kzu) is very receptive to our feedback and bug reports.

To see an example of how we use Moq, you can download the [source code to ASP.NET MVC 2 Release Candidate](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=37423), which includes both the project source code and over 2,000 unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio Ultimate and Premium version, there is:

> Microsoft Fakes Framework

Comment: The Microsoft Fakes Framework (previously known as "Moles") ships with VS2012/VS2013 Premium/Ultimate editions.  A good intro to using it is found here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx